# Is it OK to share unencrypted ID tokens?

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, openid-connect

Say I have two servers, A and B. The user agent would only connect to A (and to the OpenID Provider, in order to authenticate and authorize A). Is it OK for A, who trusts B and talks to B only via HTTPS, to pass on to B the (unencrypted) ID token it received from the OpenID Provider's Token Endpoint?

This is so that A can invoke operations on B, on behalf of the authenticated user, as represented by the ID token. B should be able to verify that the user was indeed authenticated to work with A (by checking the `aud` audience value of the ID token, and also the signature of the ID token to make sure it has not been tampered with, e.g. by A).

Is this considered good practice? Or is this supposed to be done some other way?

Also, should A in this case, when requesting the ID token, add the client-id of B to the `aud` list? It seems that's what it is good for, although I don't see the point - or do OpenID Authorization Endpoints in practice display the audience (but certainly not the client-ids which would mean nothing to an end user) to the end user to get their consent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like an OAuth use case where the user would sign on to RP A with OpenID Connect but then A uses the access token that was provided as part of the OpenID Connect flow to call B on behalf of the user.

No need to pass the ID token and do awkward stuff like sharing a `aud` identifier or even a client secret. B can inspect the access token to find out about the user and whether A has the appropriate "scope" (permissions) to call B.

It is not good practice to share ID tokens as they are meant for a specific recipient.

The access token received in the OpenID Connect flow can be associated with more than just the userinfo endpoint by included extra requested scopes in the Authentication Request.

Comment: The access token can be used by B only to acquire user data from the UserInfo endpoint. I would however like B to be able to verify the identity of the user, and verify user consent, by looking at data sent from A to B, without having to trust B, and without further interaction with the OpenID Provider. So I want authentication and authorization details to be sent from A to B, and those details should signed by the OpenID Provider for B to verify. I will see if I can rework the original question.

Comment: the access token can be used for calling other APIs than just the user info endpoint, by having the client requesting additional scopes

Comment: I was under the false impression that an auth token was just some opaque identifier to be exchanged for actual data at the OpenID provider UserInfo endpoint, but having done my homework, the auth token a) contains the consented claims and b) is signed by the OpenID provider. That's all I need! I finally understand your answer.

Comment: Minor correction: The auth token **may** be opaque - and to the client should consider it opaque - but [it does not have to be](http://nimbusds.com/blog/implementing-oauth-2-0-access-tokens/): `a) The access token is an identifier that is hard to guess [...] b) The access token self-contains the authorisation information in a manner that can be verified, e.g. by encoding the authorisation information along with a signature into the token.`. This decision is made by the Token Endpoint - which is under my control, in my case.

Comment: In the meantime I [figured](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36615882/709537) that I can put arbitrary data into the ID token as well. What difference does it make, I wonder, from a security and technical standpoint, whether I put my authorization data into the ID token or the Access token?

Comment: it differs in semantics and how and where the tokens are used; the id_token is meant for the Client and stays with the client; the Access token is meant for the/a resource server and the Client is merely the presenter; besides that an id_token represents a logged in user, an access token represents some sort of delegated permission which does not imply that the user is logged in at the moment that the token is used

Comment: Then it looks like only the OpenID provider knows or should know what is inside an access token. But that would mean I'd have to put stuff into the ID token which you said shouldn't be shared willy-nilly. So I guess the specs leave this open and I'm gonna do it the way that works best for me. Although I had the impression the id token is for establishing the user's identity, i.e. authentication, whereas the access token handles authorization.