# Is it possible to combine the "get token" and "get userinfo" step into one?

Tags: authentication, authorization, single-sign-on, openid-connect, oauth-2.0

In Authorization Code Flow, a client normally gets *id token* and *access token* in one step, and then passes the *access token* to the userinfo endpoint to get the actual data in a second step.

In terms of the OpenID Connect, is it possible to combine those steps into one, so one roundtrip from client to OpenID provider suffices?

N.B. The actual content of the Access Token is up to the implementor of an OpenID provider, so in theory I could put the data in there - but that does not seem like good practice, or is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to OpenId Connect [spec](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html):

> ID Tokens MAY contain other Claims.

And the spec also defines a set of standard [claims](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#StandardClaims)

If *id token* contains user information claims that you want, you can get these user information claims from the *id token* directly.

Comment: Hmm. So I can put arbitrary claims into ID tokens. And the content of access tokens is completely up to the implementor. Which gives me more options than I asked for... In that case it would seem to me that auth tokens would be the better place to put that data?